# Nuxt middleware: How to access vuex store?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to block user on **client-side** from editing another user's profile. My URL structure is like so:

`/users/edit/XpuBjKFoLSRHJAloNg38Amqn2jQ2`

Thus, if user tries to acccess path of another user (ie, `http://localhost:3000/users/edit/blahdasd`) I need to redirect him to homepage.

I tried to set up an anonymous middle ware like so on my page:

```
export default {
  middleware({ store, params, redirect }) {
    if (store.state.user.currentUser.uid !== params.uid) {
      return redirect('/')
    }
  },
```

But, I get page error of:

`Cannot read property 'uid' of null`

So, how do I correctly access the store here? I have no problem accessing uid from computed property on same page:

```
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user.currentUser
    },
```

Update (more information):

Here is my edit user profile page:

```
export default {
  middleware({ store, params, redirect }) {
    if (store.state.user.currentUser.uid !== params.uid) {
      // return redirect('/')
      console.log(store.state.user.currentUser.uid)
      console.log(params.uid)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.state.user.currentUser
    },
```

And here is my `store/user.js` file:

```
export const state = () => ({
  currentUser: null,
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_AUTH_USER(state, payload) {
    state.currentUser = payload
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async onAuthStateChangedAction({ commit, dispatch }, { authUser }) {
    console.log('auth state changed....')
    try {
      if (authUser && authUser.emailVerified) {
        const {
          uid,
          email,
          emailVerified,
          displayName = '',
          photoURL,
          metadata,
          providerData,
          providerId,
          tenantId
        } = authUser
        commit('SET_AUTH_USER', {
          uid,
          email,
          emailVerified,
          displayName,
          photoURL,
          metadata,
          providerData,
          providerId,
          tenantId
        })
        console.log('fetching profile...')
        await dispatch('getUserProfile', authUser)
      } else {
        console.log('User logged out or not verified')
        return null
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error with Auth State observer: ', error)
    }

  },
```

Comment: Syntax looks correct, can you give some more information? For example, how/when is your store populated with the user data? If you could share your store code and login logic, that would help :)

Comment: added more info! Hope it helps!

Comment: Again, code looks good! So I’m now wondering— how is the user navigating to (your example) http://localhost:3000/users/edit/blahdasd? Could it be that navigating to this endpoint is a hard-refresh and causes the store to flush?

Comment: Let me investigate and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is going on. I have vue devtools open and it seems the store is not done loading when the page is rendered. If I hardcode the values it works fine...